# How to make one div animation affect anothers

Tags: jquery

Hi here is a link to a jsfiddle i am working on: http://jsfiddle.net/edddotcom/7NQKU/6/

The idea is when you click on one image its container enlarges and shows some text, now if you then click on the second image the first image should then contract back to the smaller textless state,

I cant think of a way that i can make it so when one image is clicked all images except `this` should contract (if they are in the larger state)

I will be using more than 2 images so i need to make this rule apply to all the other n-1 images

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="container">
        <img src="http://cloudsmaker.com/hipsterwall/img/salto-al-norte.jpg"> <span>TEXT HERE TEXT HERE TEXT HERE TEXT HERE TEXT HERE TEXT HERE TEXT HERE TEXT HERE TEXT HERE TEXT HERE TEXT HERE TEXT HERE TEXT HERE TEXT HERE TEXT HERE TEXT HERE TEXT HERE TEXT HERE TEXT HERE TEXT HERE TEXT HERE </span>

    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <img src="http://cloudsmaker.com/hipsterwall/img/salto-al-norte.jpg"> <span>TEXT HERE TEXT HERE TEXT HERE TEXT HERE TEXT HERE TEXT HERE TEXT HERE TEXT HERE TEXT HERE TEXT HERE TEXT HERE TEXT HERE TEXT HERE TEXT HERE TEXT HERE TEXT HERE TEXT HERE TEXT HERE TEXT HERE TEXT HERE TEXT HERE </span>

    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <img src="http://cloudsmaker.com/hipsterwall/img/salto-al-norte.jpg"> <span>TEXT HERE TEXT HERE TEXT HERE TEXT HERE TEXT HERE TEXT HERE TEXT HERE TEXT HERE TEXT HERE TEXT HERE TEXT HERE TEXT HERE TEXT HERE TEXT HERE TEXT HERE TEXT HERE TEXT HERE TEXT HERE TEXT HERE TEXT HERE TEXT HERE </span>

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.row {
    max-width: 1500px;
}
.container {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 116px;
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
}
span {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    max-height: 100%;
    text-align: justify;
}
img {
    width:100%;
    max-width: 400px;
    min-width: 200px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //ON CLICK
    $("span").hide();
    $("img").toggle(function () { //fired the first time
        $(this).parent().animate({
            //FIRSTCLICK COMMAND
            height: "400px",
            width: "400px"

        }, function () {
            $(this).children("span").show();
        });
        //Enlarges container then shows text

    }, function () { // fired the second time 
        $(this).siblings("span").hide(0, '', function () {
            $(this).parent(".container").animate({
                //SECONDCLICK COMMAND
                height: "116px",
                width: "200px"
            });
        });

    }); //Hides text then contracts container

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're in an event handler and `this` is the current image, you can select all images except the current one like this:

```
 $(".container img").not(this)
```

This will allow you to operate on all the other images.  If, among those other images, you want to know which one is expanded, you can either examine the container size or you can put a class on the expanded one.  If you put a special class on the expanded one, then you can find the expanded ones with your own selector:

```
$(".container.expanded")
```

Or, examine the size:

```
$(".container").not(this).each(function() {
    if ($(this).height() > 200) {
        // this container is expanded so we need to contract it
    }
});
```

---

In your specific code, it looks you could change this:

```
$(this).siblings("span").hide...
```

to this:

```
// within our row, find all containers except the current container
$(this).closest(".row")
    .find(".container").not($(this).closest(".container"))
    .find("span").hide...
```

Comment: I added a specific code recommendation for how to change your code.

Comment: Also, great idea about the changing of the classes, it should neaten up the JavaScript quite a bit